# Laravel migration doesn't create foreign key on a different database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to add a foreign key relation with a table in other_database. Migration command runs whole migration without any error; code creates tables with no error; but **doesn't create a foreign key** relation.

```
Schema::connection($my_database_connection)->create('product_metas', 
    function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer("product_id")->references('id')->on('other_database.products');
```

What would be my mistake in foreign key relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to specify your column and then set it as a foreign key:

```
$table->unsignedInteger("product_id");
$table->foreign("product_id")->references('id')->on('other_database.products');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Schema::connection($my_database_connection)->create('product_metas', 
    function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer("product_id")->unsigned();
        $table->foreign("product_id")->references('id')->on('other_database.products');
```